# How do I display a form using CakePHP that has radio buttons?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.0

I am some what new to CakePHP and wanted some assistance in setting up a form in a CakePHP View.

I have Array in the following form:

```
Array ( [1] => B002I0HJZO [2] => B002I0HJzz [3] => B002I0HJccccccccc )
```

I want a form with 3 radio buttons (in this case) that goes to a custom method called test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with the `FormHelper` class.

Example:

```
<?php
$options = array(
  1 => 'B002I0HJZO',
  2 => 'B002I0HJzz',
  3 => 'B002I0HJccccccccc',
);

echo $this->Form->input('option_id', array('options' => $options, 'type' => 'radio'));
```

The key is to specify the "type". CakePHP usually defaults to a `select` element by default.

The example above doesn't use the "automagic" feature of CakePHP.  If you retrieve the options in your controller using a `find('list')` and the array is passed to the view in the plural form of the field name without the "_id" suffix (e.g. if the field is "option_id", you should do `$this->set('options', $this->Option->find('list');` assuming that "Option" is the model name), then you shouldn't need to specify the "options", just the "type"

To answer the second part of your question, to post to a different action (e.g. "test"), you need to specify the action when creating the form.

**Example:**

```
<?php
$this->Form->create('Product', array('action' => 'test'));
```

For more information, read the [documentation](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html)